# Fascinated by or with?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

Do I use *by* or *with* with *fascinated*?

> Fascinated by a chance to go there
>   Fascinated with a chance to go there

Collins (at [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fascinate)) says...

> A person can be fascinated by or with another person or thing. It is correct to speak of someone's fascination with a person or thing; one can also say a person or thing has a fascination for someone

...which doesn't actually help to distinguish which preposition to use. Although Collins says either **can** be used, a change in preposition usually changes the meaning.

How do I decide which of *by* or *with* to use with *fascinated*?

Comment: Welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. It is customary hereabouts to try to answer one's own question using readily available reference sources before posting it to the community, and to include some record of or reference to those efforts in posting the question, if those efforts have been finally unsuccessful. Try thefreedictionary.com (an aggregator of dictionary entries) on this one, under [*fascinate*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fascinate). In particular, check out the the usage note from the *Collins English Dictionary.*

Comment: @BrianDonovan I've added the reference for the OP and made an ELU question out of it, I hope. (Cathy, this is the sort of thing this site needs)

Answer (score 2):

One way to get an idea of how often these two are used is [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fascinated%20by%2Cfascinated%20with&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfascinated%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfascinated%20with%3B%2Cc0)
[image: picture]
This suggests that "by" is more common, but "with" is often used as well.

To do more investigation, go to that Ngram page, click on some links at the bottom and read how they were used in actual texts.